# Solving linear equations with numeric.js

Tags: linear-algebra, numeric

I must be missing something really simple here. I've got some JS code that creates simple linear systems (I'm trying to create the shortest line between two skew lines). I've gotten to the point where I have Ax = b, and need to solve for x. A is a 3 x 2 matrix, b is 3 x 1.

I have:

```
function build_equation_system(v1, v2, b) { 
    var a = [ [v1.x, v2.x], [v1.y, v2.y], [v1.z, v2.z] ];
    var b = [ [b.x], [b.y], [b.z]];
    return numeric.solve(a,b)
}
```

Numeric returns a 1 x 3 matrix of NaNs, even when there is a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using numeric you can do the following:

Create a function which computes the pseudoinverse of your A matrix:

```
function pinv(A) {
    return numeric.dot(numeric.inv(numeric.dot(numeric.transpose(A),A)),numeric.transpose(A));
}
```

Use that function to solve your linear least squares equation to get the coefficients.

```
var p = numeric.dot(pinv(a),b);
```

I tried your initial method of using `numeric.solve` and could not get it to work either so I'd be interested to know what the problem is.

A simple test...

```
var x = new Array(10);
var y = new Array(10);
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { 
    x[i] = i;
    y[i] = i;
}
// Solve for the first order equation representing this data
var n = 1;
// Construct Vandermonde matrix.
var A = numeric.rep([x.length, n + 1], 1);
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
    for (var j = n-1; j >= 0; --j) {
        A[i][j] = x[i] * A[i][j+1];
    }
}

// Solves the system Ap = y
var p = numeric.dot(pinv(A),y);
```

p = [1, 2.55351295663786e-15]

I've used this method to recreate MATLAB's polyfit for Javascript use.